# How to make listings with mathematics notations?

Tags: listings

I have a problem about make a listing program and I want make it like this:

[image: Tes]

For my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underbrace{Example1}_{Example2}$\\
\\
$\overbrace{EXample}^{Example}$
\end{document}
```

But, I want to replace `Example1` and `Example2` with:

```
\lstinline+\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]+
\lstinline+Pilihan+
```

And Replace Example3 and  Example4 with:

```
\lstinline+\documentclass{article}+
\lstinline+Pilihan Kelas+
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Where is the math in this? Otherwise, I would suggest the `tcolorbox` for quite nice listings.

Comment: I think he means the braces above and below the code.

Comment: @Astrinus yes, you true how to make it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *must* do this, it is possible with `tikzmark`. But watch out that you choose an appropriate escape character, which is never used in the listing itself.

I would not recommend it though. It requires manual edits to your listing source, which may or may not be feasible, depending on the length of the listing. There are also better, clearer ways to explain source code than this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX},escapechar=|]
|\tikzmark{mark1begin}|\documentclass[<options>]|\tikzmark{mark1end}|{|\tikzmark{mark2begin}|<class name>|\tikzmark{mark2end}|}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[overlay,decorate,decoration={brace},yshift=2ex] 
    (pic cs:mark1begin) -- (pic cs:mark1end) node[midway,above] {[illegible]};
  \draw[overlay,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},yshift=-0.3em] 
    (pic cs:mark2begin) -- (pic cs:mark2end) node[midway,below] {[illegible]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt, but I am not sure what the OP really requires.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,arc=0mm,auto outer arc}
\documentclass[<options>]{<documentclassname>}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{section}

\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want make math mode and listing environments

Comment: @Hirwanto: Could you explain what you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
$\texttt{\textbackslash}\overbrace{\texttt{documentclass[<options>]}}^{\textrm{above text}}\underbrace{\texttt{\{<options<\}}}_{\textrm{below text}}$
```

Next time post a better quality image, please.

EDIT: after your edit, I think you can't mix math mode and listing environments... Mine is a workaround.

Comment: I hope, there are not more code lines than just the one posted in the image, otherwise it could be tedious to do this like you proposed ;-)

Comment: @Astrinus, How to make it with listings package ?

Comment: As said in the edited answer, I don't know. Math mode and listing environments are treated very different by TeX.

Comment: @Astrinus, Yeah, i want to make math mode and listing environments,

Comment: @Hirwanto what I'm saying is that I think there's no way to make them work together.

Comment: @Astrinus , Why ?

Comment: Long story short (=it is not this, but is quite similar): Math mode has a special treatment by the TeX (not LaTeX!) engine, whereas `listings` expects to work in text mode and makes some tweaks on this basis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17651/discussion-between-hirwanto-and-astrinus).

Comment: I have problem using the chat (related to the Internet connection). You'd better wait for someone more expert than me.